# Python replace function doesn't work in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, replace

I'm currently running python for windows version 3.8.0. I can run the code below and it works fine on my Linux machine but doesn't print out anything in windows.

```
a = "This is the island of istanbul"
b = a.replace("is" , "was")
print (b)
```

Comment: How do you start it? Have you tried with the simplest possible one-liner print("Hello World")?

Comment: The code will behave the same in both Windows and Linux (and all other OS's for that matter).  It's likely that it's just not printing to where you expect.  How are you running this code?

Comment: I'm using the code exactly as it appears above. It prints hello world just fine.

Comment: Can you run the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) on windows and enter the code line by line. Does it work then?

Comment: How do you "use" the code? You must somehow start the Python interpreter to execute it.

Comment: it's just in a .py file and i use it by typing "python myfile.py" or "python3 myfile.py" either way it doesn't work.

Comment: It works fine in REPL

Comment: What happens if you replace the last line with print(repr(b)) ?

Comment: still prints nothing

Comment: So output is either redirected or the program silently crashes before it can print. For me a damaged Python installation is the most probable explanation.

Comment: It doesn't print any error message. Even started it with "start /wait python.exe myfile.py" and checked the "%errorlevel%" variable in windows. It returned 0 as it should. This is very strange indeed.

Comment: Run `where.exe python` to make sure it's running the right `python` command.

Comment: Sorry to ask but are you sure that the Python script you are editing is the file you are running (right directory)? Have you also tried to delete the related .pyc or .pyo file (compiled bytecode)? I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code and it worked fine, except it printed "Thwas was the wasland of wastanbul", unless that's what's intended to be printed.
If you want the code to print "This was the island of istanbul" you would need to add spaces on your replace method.

```
a = "This is the island of istanbul"
b = a.replace(" is ", " was ")
print(b)
```

Comment: It doesn't print anything at all on my machine.

Comment: What are you using to run it?(An IDE, command prompt, a python shell, etc.)

Comment: Try running small programs such as printing "hello world" and then add variables to try and locate the problem.  You may need to run the Python installer and click on repair. Example of what I was talking about run a program that prints hello world, if that doesn't work, you know you need to repair your Python.

Comment: I'm trying to suggest ideas it's just a little hard for everyone when something doesn't work when it's a world of possibilities of what happened.

Comment: Try repairing your Python installation, it can't hurt anything

Comment: I went through the repair process with the installer file. Rebooted my machine. Still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when i installed Microsoft Visual Studio Code it also installed it's own version of python in a different location.

Running where.exe python i get:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32.exe
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

So that was causing all the problems all along.

Thanks to user eryk-sun for suggesting what to look for.

Comment: "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" is the regular per-user installation of 32-bit Python 3.8. "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe" is the app distribution of Python that installs from the Microsoft Store. If you haven't installed the app distribution, this "python.exe" is a program that opens the store site to install it.